# How to take last hidden state of bidirectional LSTM in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, sequence-to-sequence

I'm not sure how to select the last hidden/cell states in a bidirectional LSTM in Pytorch.

```
output, (hn, cn) = bi_lstm(input, (h0, c0))
```

How can I use  `output`,  `hn` and `cn` in order to extract the last forward and backward hidden states?

In the case of backward LSTM, I want to extract the hidden state I get after processing the entire sequence backwards.